# HAproxy replace the path in html

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy, proxypass

I have a HAproxy which will forward http://proxy.server/foo/foo/bar to http://backend.server/bar. the setting is working well.

However, if the html file hosted in **backend.server** is loading some resource such as `<script src="/bar" >`, it will not work (correct one should be `<script src="/foo/foo/bar" >`).

How can I set the HAProxy to rewrite the HTML, once it sees **/bar**, it will automatically amend it and add back the **/foo/foo/bar** ?

My Setting in HAproxy backend is as below:

`reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /foo/foo/(.*)     \1\ /\2`

Answer (score -1):

HAProxy does not rewrite HTML.

Comment: Actually it does using Lua https://www.arpalert.org/haproxy-lua.html